Residue at infinity is the coefficient of $z$ of the Laurent expansion?
I would like to see if the following statement is true or false.
Let $g$ be an analytic function on the region $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert>R\}$ for some $R > 0$. We define the residue $\mathrm{Res}(g,\infty) = -\mathrm{Res}(h,0)$ where $h(z)=z^{-2}g(1/z)$. Does it follow that $\mathrm{Res}(g,\infty)$ is the coefficient of $z$ in the Laurent series of $g$ in the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert>R\}$?
If I am not mistaken, I think this statement is false. For example, let $R=1$ and consider the following function $$g(z)=z^3-7z^2+8z+5-3z^{-1}+11z^{-2}$$ which is clearly analytic on $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z \rvert > 1\}$ because it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Since $g$ is already in its Laurent series, its coefficient of $z$ is 8.
From the above definition of residue at infinity, we have
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}g\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{1}{z^5}-\frac{7}{z^4}+\frac{8}{z^3} + \frac{5}{z^2} - \frac{3}{z} + 11.$$
Its residue is $-3$, and therefore $\mathrm{Res}(g,\infty)=3 \neq 8$.
I for sure might have made a dumb error somewhere. I would appreciate if you could pinpoint any errors in this example! Thank you again.

it is not the coefficient of $z$ but it is still the coefficient of $1/z$ - note that the point of the residue is to measure how far the integral on a circle is away from zero and then it doesnt matter if we go to zero or to infinity $\int_{|z|=R|}z^kdz$ is still non zero iff $k=-1$

The main point is that we calculate the residue of a meromorphic differential ($1$-form) rather than of a meromorphic function. This is the notion that stays well-defined if you change coordinates. So at infinity, we introduce $z=1/w$ and
$$f(z)\,dz = f(1/w)\left(\frac{-dw}{w^2}\right) = \left(-\frac{f(1/w)}{w^2}\right)dw.$$
When you consider the Laurent expansion in the region $\{z:|z|>R\}$, you are working in the region $\{w:|w|<1/R\}$, and so
$$f(z)\,dz=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n\,dz = -\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nw^{-n}\frac{dw}{w^2}=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nw^{-n-2}\,dw.$$
The residue at $0$ of the latter is $-a_{-1}$. The negative sign, if you like, accounts for the reversal of the orientation of the circle when we go around $\infty$ rather than around $0$.
